# Allowing both moving and copying a returned class member

Tags: c++, c++14

I'm trying to write a class that contains a function returning one of the class members, and I want to allow the caller to either move or copy the returned value. I wrote some dummy structs to test this; and after trying different variations, this seems to give me what I want.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct S {
  int x;
  S() : x(10) { cout << "ctor called\n"; }
  S(const S& s) : x(s.x) { cout << "copy ctor called\n"; }
  S(S&& s) : x(s.x) { cout << "move ctor called\n"; }
  // I'm implementing move and copy the same way since x is an int. 
  // I just want to know which one gets called.
};

struct T {
  S s;
  T() : s() {}
  S&& Test() && {
    return move(s);
  }  
  const S& Test() & {
    return s;
  }  
};

int main() {
  T t;
  auto v = move(t).Test();  
  cout << v.x << "\n";  
  T t2;
  auto w = t2.Test();
  cout << w.x << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

The code prints out (with clang++-5.0 c++14):

```
ctor called
move ctor called
10
ctor called
copy ctor called
10
```

Is this an acceptable way to implement what I want? I have a few questions:

1. In the first Test function, I tried both `S&&` and `S` for the return type and it doesn't change the output. Does `&&` mean anything for the (non-template) returned type?
2. Is it guaranteed that `auto v = move(t).Test()` would only invalidate the "moved" member? If struct `T` had other member variables, can I assume this call wouldn't invalidate them?

Comment: It would be better to give remove rvalue qualifier from a moving method and just give methods more appropriate names, such as `Move_S` and `Get_S`. 1. Probably extra constructor call got elided. 2. Nothing is invalided. Object state after move is not specified in general, but in your case it is clearly defined to be the same valid state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In the first Test function, I tried both `S&&` and `S` for the return type and it doesn't change the output. Does `&&` mean anything for the (non-template) returned type?

There are little differences:

- `S&&` is a (r-value) reference, so object is not yet moved.
- returning `S` would move-construct `S`, so member is moved once the method is called.

For `move(t).Test();`, return ing`S&&` does nothing whereas returning `S` would move the member.

> Is it guaranteed that auto v = move(t).Test() would only invalidate the "moved" member? If struct T had other member variables, can I assume this call wouldn't invalidate them?

Yes, only `T::s` is moved. `std::move` is just a cast to `rvalue`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is acceptable way to implement this.

1. It does the same thing because returned value is temporary object, thus rvalue.
2. Depends on what you mean by invalidating